# llamada desde ajax a php en un mismo archivo

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo dos archivos uno donde se encuentra el codigo ajax y otro donde esta el php. ¿Se puede llamar desde la URL en ajax al codigo PHP dentro del mismo archivo? 
Algo como en html:

```
<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

pero en ajax

```
$.ajax({
   url:"codigo php en mismo archivo que codigo ajax" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer no colocando el campo url:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: {value: value},
  success: function(e){
    // Código
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola Johanm!, una opción que veo posible es especificar en **url** el archivo PHP, es decir algo como esto:

```
$.ajax({
     url:"http://localhost/tuproyecto/archivo.php" })
```

Claro que tu estructura de archivos puede que sea diferente, pero creo por el momento que eso te puede servir.

Y otra cosa muy importante, si deseas llamar al mismo archivo tendrías que **controlar el tipo de **petición http**** que le estas haciendo con AJAX. Esto lo puedes hacer utilizando la variable global de PHP **$_SERVER**, aquí un ejemplo:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'POST'){
     // Tu código
};
```

Si deseas **controlar más de un tipo de petición http** te recomiendo que utilices un **switch**:

```
switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
    case 'POST':
        // Tu código
    break;

    case 'GET':
        // Tu código
    break;
    case 'PUT':
        // Tu código
    break;

    case 'DELETE':
        // Tu código
    break;

};
```

Espero que esto te haya sido de ayuda, un saludo colega. :)